# Using simple grid with Foundation 6 Zurb Stack

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm trying to prototype a site using the Zurb Stack project (since I want SASS and Handlebars), and I need to use the plain vanilla grid in order to support IE9. However my layout isn't working (even when copied direct from the tutorials), and looking into dist/assets/css/app.css I've discovered that it lacks the necessary classes such as .row and .column. Is there a setting I need to configure in order to switch from the newer grids to the old row/column version? I've searched the Zurb site and the wider internet in vain.

Comment: Found the solution myself - foundation-grid was commented out in src/assets/scss/_settings.scss. I guess I'll find my way around eventually!

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the framework to use the legacy *Float Grid*, you need to go to app.scss remove comment on the line where shows `@include foundation-grid;`, and comment the one with `@include foundation-xy-grid-classes;`, then rebuild framework.

Hope this helps

Comment: Indeed - I found those lines eventually!

Comment: You could award me the answer ;)

Comment: I up-voted it, but because I'm new my vote doesn't affect the display :(